# Error init Datatable with iDisplayLength

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a HTML page using datatables 1.10.15.
This function works fine

```
 <script th:inline="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#companyTable').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

But not this one

```
 <script th:inline="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $("#companyTable").dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength"    : 25;
    });    
} );
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Use `pageLength` instead of `iDisplayLength`.

Comment: same result ;-(

Comment: Use `$("#companyTable").DataTable({......})` ..

Comment: Remove the `;` from   `"iDisplayLength"    : 25;` I guess you have a big fat red error in the console. FYI: `iDisplayLength` and `pageLength` is synonyms, it doesnt matter which you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script th:inline="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#companyTable').dataTable( {
     "pageLength": 25
   } );  
} );
</script>
```